# How to fix "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I keep getting this "Index was outside the bounds of the array" exception.  I have a datatable with filenames.  There is a listbox on the webform page connected to the tabletable.  I am trying to select multiple options from the listbox.  Then send each filename to an handler .ashx file.  I'm using a for loop as you'll see.

here is the main.aspx.cs code:

```
namespace MultiImagesImageHandler
{
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] AllselectedIndex = ListBox1.GetSelectedIndices();
        int a = AllselectedIndex.Length;

        DataView tempDV = SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;

        for (int i = 0; i < a + 1; i++)
        {
            string fn = tempDV.Table.Rows[AllselectedIndex[i+1]].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            ImgHandler.filename[i] = fn.Trim();
        }

        Response.Redirect("image1.htm");

    }
}
}
```

the handler.ashx.cs code:

```
namespace MultiImagesImageHandler
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for ImgHandler
/// </summary>
public class ImgHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public static string[] filename = new string[16];


    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string saveTo = @"fileLocation" + filename[3];
        FileStream writeStream1 = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        string loadFrom = @"fileLocation" + filename[3];
        using (FileStream fs1 = File.Open(loadFrom, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            ReadWriteStream(fs1, writeStream1);
        }
        byte[] tt = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/images/" + filename[3]));
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
}
```

I thought this would fill the array in ImgHandler.ashx.cs with the selected filenames from the datatable, but it doesn't.  It keeps putting up this exception.  I don't know why this isn't working.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < a + 1; i++) Why did you use a + 1? this is probably your issue. It should just be i < a

Comment: change this `i < a + 1` to `i < a` and learn to use a debugger

Comment: You should't do a+1 in your for loop as u go out of bounds

Comment: What part of the exception message did you not understand?

Comment: There is another error in your code `tempDV.Table.Rows[AllselectedIndex[i+1]]` It seems that you are selecting the wrong row from your datatable. And what do you think will happen if your user select the last item from your ListBox1?

Comment: I added the a+1 after getting this same error with just a.  It was Steve that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a + 1; i++)
{
    string fn = tempDV.Table.Rows[AllselectedIndex[i+1]].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    ImgHandler.filename[i] = fn.Trim();
}
```

Change the "a + 1" to just "a"

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I also had to change AllselectedIndex[I+1] to just i.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a + 1; i++)
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string sRecontent = txtrepalcecontent.Text;
  string[] fileLineString = new string[sContent.Length];
  for (int i =0 ; i < sContent.Length; i++)

  {
      //fileLineString[0] = sContent[0].ToString();
      string[] content = sContent.Split(delim);
      if (sFind == content[i])  **//index was outside the bounds the array**
      {
          string A = sContent.Remove(i, txtfind.Text.Length);
          string S = A.Insert(i, sReplace);
          txtrepalcecontent.Text = S;
      }
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add details in your answer. Add information like what is wrong and what is it that you are changing.